# Creating array with relations between identifiers

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Consider the following toy array `a`:

```
a = np.array([[1074279, 937077, 1445858, 1679465], 
              [1074280, 1023600, 1679465, 937077],  
              [1074281, 908450, 1932761, 1100360],  
              [1074282, 1445858, 893656, 908183], 
              [1074283, 1958030, 1932761, 1445858]])
```

The first column is an identifier.

How can I transform the array in a way that shows when an identifier is related
to another? *A relation exists if two identifiers have in common at least one
value in columns `2`-`4` of `a`*.

The end result should be the array `b` below:

```
b = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

This can perhaps better be understood as follows:

```
         1074279 1074280 1074281 1074282 1074283
1074279     1       1       0       1       1
1074280     1       1       0       0       0
1074281     0       0       1       0       1
1074282     1       0       0       1       1
1074283     1       0       1       1       1
```

I have tried (double) looping over elements to find all the combinations and 
then reduce that to the desired array but I cannot get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outer-equality does the job for a vectorized solution -

```
In [90]: np.equal.outer(a[:,1:],a[:,1:]).any(axis=(1,3)).view('i1')
Out[90]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

**Explanation**

Basically, we are performing pairwise equality comparison for all rows and within each row pairwise equality comparison with `np.equal.outer(..)`. The equality comparison is a 4D array. Thus, for the slice `a[:,1:]` being `(m,n)` shaped, would give us a equality comparison array of shape `(m,n,m,n)`. So, then we `ANY` reduce it along the axes - `1` and `3` to give us a 2D boolean array of shape `(m,m)` and that's our final output after conversion to an int array.

An alternative with explicit dimension-expansion would be -

```
In [92]: (a[:,1:,None,None]==a[:,1:]).any(axis=(1,3)).view('i1')
Out[92]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

So, the only change is that we are adding new axes for the first version of the slice with [`None/np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) to create a 4D version. This is then compared against the original 2D version to result in the 4D equality compared boolean array.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler classic solution that is easily understandable:

```
def has_in_common(a1, a2):
    """
    @param a1, a2: two input arrays
    @returns True if a1 and a2 has at least one value in common, otherwise False
    """
    for v1 in a1[1:]:
        for v2 in a2[1:]:
            if v1 == v2:
                return True
    return False
```

```
def relation_matrix(a):
    """
    @param a: an input array
    @returns m a matrix specifying the relationship between the rows of a
    ex: a = [[1074279, 937077, 1445858, 1679465], 
              [1074280, 1023600, 1679465, 937077],  
              [1074281, 908450, 1932761, 1100360],  
              [1074282, 1445858, 893656, 908183], 
              [1074283, 1958030, 1932761, 1445858]]
        m = [[1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
        more precisely
        m =      1074279 1074280 1074281 1074282 1074283
        1074279     1       1       0       1       1
        1074280     1       1       0       0       0
        1074281     0       0       1       0       1
        1074282     1       0       0       1       1
        1074283     1       0       1       1       1
    """

    m = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[0]))
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a)):
            if has_in_common(a[i], a[j]):
                m[i, j] = 1
    return m.astype('int')
```

Demo:

```
In [1]:relation_matrix(a)
Out[1]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```